# matrix product between linked list sparse matrix

Tags: c, matrix, linked-list, sparse-matrix

i've rappresented my sparse matrix in that form, using **C** language:

```
typedef struct node
{
    int column;
    int value;
    int row;
    struct node *next;
} element;
```

i've got  an Insert function that add an element in the matrix, here's the declaration:

```
 void Insert(element *x[], int row, int column, int value)
```

my question is: how i can implement a function that compute the product between two sparse matrix in that form?

here's is my tentative:

```
void dotProduct( element * ptrA , element * ptrB ) {
    element* initB = ptrB;
    int sum = 0;
    while( ptrA!=NULL ) {
        ptrB = initB;
        int column, int row;
        while( ptrB!=NULL ) {
            if( ptrA->row == ptrB->column ) {
                column = ptrb->column;
                sum = sum + ptra->value*ptrB->value;
                row = ptrA->row;
            }
            ptrB = ptr->next;
        }
        ptrA = ptrA->next;
    }
    insert( row, column, sum )
}
```

Comment: Would help to know if the elements were in a specific order.

Comment: no, not are in a specific order

Comment: This is a bad approach. You should link nodes in X and Y direction. And format your code better. Spaces are not just for indentation.

Comment: And specifically: don't indent the loop step at a different level to the rest of the block. The aim of indentation is to visualise blocks.

Comment: Seems odd -- is this supposed to be *dot* product or *matrix* product. Your question says one thing but your function name says something else. Also -- what is the point of computing something only to throw it away? I don't see why you would want `dotProduct` to return `void`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a good start. But your `sum` variable is computing the sum of all elements of the result matrix. That's not what you want.

Here is what I would change.

1) Instead of a scalar integer `int sum = 0` use a sparse matrix `elment *result = NULL`. You want to add the value to a specific element of the matrix, not to a scalar sum.

2)  Add a function to add increase the value of a matrix element (row, column) by an int value

```
void Add(element *x[], int row, int column, int value){
    element *ptr = x;
    while (ptr != NULL) {
        if (ptr->row == row && ptr->column == column) {
            ptr->value += value;
            return;
        }
    }

    /* We could not find an existing element with given row and column
       Create a new one */
    Insert(x, row, column, value)
 }
```

3) Replace `sum = sum + ptra->value*ptrB->value;` with `Add(result, row, column, ptra->value*ptrB->value);`

4) You can get rid of your final `insert( row, column, sum )`. It won't compile as it has only 3 parameters. By the time your outer `while` loop completes, you'll have a computed product in the sparse matrix `result` anyway.